# returning negative matches in Postgres

Tags: postgresql

Let us say that I want to find rows that contain a match. For example:

`select * from tableName where tableName.colName like '%abc%' limit 5;`

This is going to give me rows that contain the substring `abc` within the column `colName` in the table `tableName`. Now, how do I get rows rows where the column colName does *not* contain the string `abc`. Is there some sort of a negation operator in Postgres?

Comment: `select * from tableName where tableName.colName not like '%abc%' limit 5;` ?..

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-logical.html

Answer (score 2):

Use `not like`:

```
select * from tableName where tableName.colName not like '%abc%' limit 5;
```

Comment: Depending on what the OP wants, you might want to also include `or colname is not null`

Comment: @Hambone Can you explain your thinking?  If the column be `NULL` then the current check would fail, which makes sense to me.

Comment: I *think* that if you say field != 'value' then a null does *not* come back.  A null value is not NOT 'value' -- it's nothing.  I believe the same is true for `not in` and `not like`.  I could totally be wrong, but I thought for sure I've been bit in the back side by using a `!=` or a `not in` expecting nulls to come back, but they don't.

Comment: Here's a quick example...  `with foo as (select 'one' as bar union all select null union all select 'two') select * from foo where bar not like '%three%'`